# Popup window for points using Leaflet.Vectorgrid, error 'lat' of undefined

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have this error

> "leaflet.js:5, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined".

The points shows fine with the style and all but as soon as I want to click on a point, nothing shows and I get this error in developer tool.

Any idea what is missing?

Thanks

```js
var points = new L.featureGroup();

    function round(value, decimals) {
    return Number(Math.round(value + 'e' + decimals) + 'e-' + decimals);
    }


                var vectorTileOptions_poi = {
                rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile,
                maxZoom: 20,
                zIndex: 100,
                vectorTileLayerStyles: {
                    sliced: function (properties, zoom){
                      var dist = properties.length
                        return {
                                radius:     dist <= 150 ? 1.5:
                                            dist >150 && dist <= 500 ? 2:
                                            dist >500 && dist <= 1000 ? 3:
                                            dist >1000 ? 4: 0,

                                fillColor:  dist <= 150 ? '#ffffff':
                                            dist >150 && dist <= 500 ? '#00cc00':
                                            dist >500 && dist <= 1000 ? '#ffff00':
                                            dist >1000 ? '#ff4d4d': '#66ffff',

                                color:      dist <= 150 ? '#ffffff':
                                            dist >150 && dist <= 500 ? '#00cc00':
                                            dist >500 && dist <= 1000 ? '#ffff00':
                                            dist >1000 ? '#ff4d4d': '#66ffff',
                                fill: true,
                                weight: 1,
                                fillOpacity: 0.8,
                                }
                    }
                },
                interactive: true,
                };

  $.getJSON("/xyz/test/points.geojson", function(json) {                     

    var newPoints =  L.vectorGrid.slicer(json, vectorTileOptions_poi)

    .on('click', function(e) {
    var properties = e.layer.properties;
      L.popup()
        .setContent(
                '<b>Point Data</b>' +
                '<br>Amount: <b>'+ properties.TOTAL + '</b>' +
                '<br>Distance: <b>' + (round(properties.length/1000, 2)) + ' km</b>' +
                '<br>Name: <b>' + properties.name + '</b>' +
                '<br>Zipcode, City: <b>' + properties.zipCode + ', ' + properties.City + '</b>'
                )

        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .openOn(map);
        L.DomEvent.stop(e);
    })
     newPoints.addTo(point)
 })
```

Comment: Did you find the problem I have the same issue with L.vectorGrid.protobuf

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet.VectorGrid is not really maintained any more, but if you look at the github of the project you'll see several developers have continued to implemented pull requests (which have not been integrated) for various issues, including this one.

You can add layer.getLatLng = null; in Leaflet.VectorGrid.js to fix the issue, see below:

```
_createLayer: function(feat, pxPerExtent, layerStyle) {
    var layer;
    switch (feat.type) {
    case 1:
        layer = new PointSymbolizer(feat, pxPerExtent);
        // [YB 2019-10-23: prevent leaflet from treating these canvas points as real markers]
        layer.getLatLng = null;         
        break;
    case 2:
        layer = new LineSymbolizer(feat, pxPerExtent);
        break;
    case 3:
        layer = new FillSymbolizer(feat, pxPerExtent);
        break;
    }

    if (this.options.interactive) {
        layer.addEventParent(this);
    }

    return layer;
}
```

Comment: thanks. No I did not find the solution I was hoping-waiting they would update as I have it linked to unpkg.com. Guess that will not happen, will look into this a bit more...

Comment: I added `layer.getLatLng=null'`  to leaflet.vectorgrid.js file in the right location but i am still getting this error